# how to run a cordova/phonegap plugin asynchrounously - fileTransfer plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, asynchronous, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have used cordova [filetransfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). I am uploading a file using fileTransfer plugin's `upload` function.
The problem is that upload works synchronously and application UI freezes while the file is being uploaded by this plugin.

I want the file upload to run asynchronously and user should be able to interact on UI while upload is in progress.

My cordova application is targeted for iOS and Windows.

I have used cordova [filetransfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer). I am uploading a file using fileTransfer plugin's `upload` function.
The problem is that upload works synchronously and application UI freezes while the file is being uploaded by this plugin.

I want the file upload to run asynchronously and user should be able to interact on UI while upload is in progress.

My cordova application is targeted for iOS and Windows.

My javascript function which calls the cordova file-transfer plugin is as below:

```
var uploadVideo = function(path) {
    //UPLOAD VIDEO TO SERVER
    var fileURL = path;
    var win = function(r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    };
    var fail = function(error) {
        console.log("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
    };
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    options.mimeType = "text/plain";
    var params = {};
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
        if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
            var perc = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
            $('progress').val(perc);
        }
    };
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://<serverpath>/<endpoint>"), win, fail, options);
};
```

As soon as this script/function is invoked, user is unable to interect with html page. Page kind of freezes and user can't input any text in text boxes or any other UI interaction.

Comment: Please add javascript code that you're using, with cordova and plugin version.

Comment: i have written my own phonegap fileupload plugin

Comment: I can't understand: first you say that you are using the filetransfer plugin, than you say that you've written a custom plugin. Please explain better your situation, and add some of the code you've used/written.

Comment: @lifeisfoo, I never mentioned about custom plugin. Its Mohammed.
Mohammed, is your plugin iOS compliant ?